# My code compiles but does not execute. Where did I go wrong? How can this be avoided in future codes?

Tags: java, methods

I'm trying to convert any roman numeral under 3,999 to a decimal number. The code compiles but never prompts me to enter the roman numeral like the scanner asks it to.

```
//necessary for the scanner  
import java.util.Scanner; 
/**
* conversion of roman numerals into decimals
* 
* @Annika Helverson 
* period 5
*/

public class Numeral
{

private static Scanner scanner = new Scanner( System.in );
public static int decimalValue (String romanNumeral) {
    int decimal = 0;
    int count = 0;
    int i = 1;
  //tell user what to do
System.out.print( "Please enter a valid roman numeral: ");
//read the submitted number
String input = scanner.nextLine();
//display input back to user
System.out.println( "input =" + input );

    while (count < romanNumeral.length ()-1 || i < romanNumeral.length ()){
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("M")){
        decimal = decimal + 1000;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("D")) {
        decimal = decimal + 500;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("C")) {
        decimal = decimal + 100;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("L")) {
        decimal = decimal + 50;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("X")) {
        decimal = decimal + 10;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("V")) {
        decimal = decimal + 5;
    }
    if (romanNumeral.substring (count, i).equals ("I")) {
        decimal = decimal + 1;
    }
    count = count + 1;
    i = i + 1;
    } 
    {
    if (romanNumeral.contains ("CM")){
    decimal = decimal - 200;
```

theres more code in here of all the "exceptions" in roman numerals.
        }
        return decimal;
        }
        }
        }

Comment: You have no main method, so no entry point. Read the section "The main Method" : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/getStarted/application/

Comment: FWIW, "code" (in the sense of source code) is a mass noun, like "water" or "air". It's never plural.

Comment: How exactly do you "execute" the above code?

Comment: @T.J.Crowder: tell that to Roger Waters... :)

Answer (score 5):

You need a main method to serve as the entry point of your program. This class is only usable if you create an object of it and call it's methods on the newly created object.

What you need is the main method:

```
public static void main(String args[]) {
    // Your code that should be executed on start, here
}
```

Don't throw all the code inside the main-method, though. That's bad practice.

Answer (score 0):

Your method `public static int decimalValue (String romanNumeral)` gets passed a string that you should probably convert. You are using a `Scanner` *inside* your `decimalValue` method, but it's supposed to be called in `main` and pass the the numeral to your method. You are probably not calling your method from main at all.